# Postman test doesn't work after console log

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

As a newbie in Postman, I'm a bit confused trying to log the test step.

[When console.log is commented - the test works fine:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZoym.png)

[But when I use console.log, it goes through all iterations, prints the value but falls on the next step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6XSt.png)

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try to loop through the JsonData array and access to the key value "symbol" by using forEach. It will probably solve your issue.

Ex:

```
JsonData.forEach(element){
      console.log(element.symbol)
     };
```

then you can push the element to the array called "a".